# How to add an item to a RecyclerView if it's height is larger than the screen size?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

A single item in my `RecyclerView` consists of 3 charts but the last one turns out minuscule. How do I make them all appear their full size/total size bigger than 1 page? 
To sum up: 1 item made up of 3 charts. Many such items in a `RecyclerView`.

Things that I've tried: 
1. `LinearLayout` with equal weights.
2. `RelativeLayouts` with the heights explicitly mentioned.

Thing I'm trying to achieve: [image]

What I have now: [image: There's a barely visible Pie chart at pos:3]

I looked at MPAndroidChart's example and it uses `ListView` and not `RecyclerView`. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: 
The answer was Wrapping the entire thing in a ScrollView.

Comment: You mean wrapping the individual items in a `ScrollView`?